# Qual a diferença entre GetCurrentProcess e GetCurrentProcessID?

Tags: delphi, processo

Qual a diferença entre a chamada `GetCurrentProcess` e o `MainHandle` definido abaixo:

```
var
  MainHandle: THandle;
begin
MainHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, GetCurrentProcessID);
end;
```

Em minha aplicação somente o `GetCurrentProcess` surte o efeito esperado, porém fiquei com dúvida da diferença entre eles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como o nome diz o [`GetCurrentProcess()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) obtêm o processo em si, ou seja, um manipulador para o processo. Você usará este manipulador para executar ações ou obter informações do processo.

E também como o nome diz o [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pegue o identificador do processo, ou seja, ele pega o o número do processo e mais nada. Ele é apenas um número que identifica o processo mas não é o processo.

A não ser que o Delphi tenha duas formas o [`OpenProcess()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) original da API da Microsoft está esperando o ID, portanto somente o segundo deveria funcionar. E mesmo que tenha como usar o manipulador além do ID ou que eles acabam se confundindo, ambos deveriam funcionar.

Pode ser que não esteja vindo o ID corretamente por alguma razão que eu desconheço, talvez ele só funcione em alguns contextos. Já tentou o [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Comment: Entendi a diferença amigo, muito obrigado elo esclarecimento